# SQL stored procedure affect rows

Tags: sql-server

Here is my store procedure :

```
create procedure insertBook2 @author varchar(32), @title varchar(32), @pages int
as
begin
    declare @identity int
    insert into inventar(author,class) values (@author,'book')
    select @IDENTITY=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    insert into book(id,title,pages) values (@identity,@title,@pages)
end
```

and table relations

```
inventar(id,class,author)
book(id,title,pages);
```

I executed procedure,but it affected 3 rows. Added one more row on table book values:    *id=id title=NULL and pages=NULL* before row with real information :/
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any triggers on these tables?

Comment: No.
 Maybe the problem is that book(id) is foreign key references inventar(id).When we insert values into inventar,we have a new tuple in book with same id and null values.instead of insert into book,update book works fine

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure looks fine in that it should create the correct number of rows, that is one in each table.

However, I see you are doing

```
select @IDENTITY=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

whereas you should really use

```
set @IDENTITY=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

as you're setting a variable, not querying a table.

That would cause you to get extra output saying "1 rows affected", which is perhaps what caused your confusion.